# Use DeMorgan's laws to prove or disprove the following:

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$(p\wedge q)\rightarrow r   =    \mathop{\sim} r\rightarrow (p\rightarrow \mathop{\sim} q)   =   (q \wedge \mathop{\sim} r)  \rightarrow  \mathop{\sim} p$

so just double checking, i know if p and q then r, means if p or q doesnt happen then not r.

Demorgans laws are the compliment of the union of two elements is equal to the intersection of the compliment of each of the two elements. Also, the compliment of the intersection of two elements = the union of the compliments of each element.

So the second one is saying if r doesnt happen then p happened and q didnt, and the third one is saying if q happened and r didnt then p must of not happened. I just don't know how to formally apply those laws to the logic im understanding. please help! have a huge final tomorrow he said this will be on the exam.

Comment: "i know if p and q then r, means if p or q doesnt happen then not r."  Um, That's not right, is it?  If I am rich and if I am handsome then July has 31 days.  But as it turns out I am ugly... but July still has 31 days.

Comment: so i am wrong......haha. so the statement is false

Comment: Can you use the fact that $p\rightarrow q$ equals $\sim p \vee q$?

Comment: The statement you made "i know if p and q then r, means if p or q doesnt happen then not r" is false.  I don't know about anything else in this post.

Comment: thank you for the correction, ill try to look into it.

Comment: The negation of an and statement is logically equivalent to the or statement in which
each component is negated. from the texbook

Comment: so p and q then r is equivalent to not p or not q then not r. so if i study and retain the knowledge ill score high. if i dont study or retain the knowledge then i wont score high.

Comment: but the last one is saying q happens and not r then p doesn't happen, idk about that.

Answer (score 1):

The first statement says that if both $p$ and $q$ are true, then $r$ is true. So, by contraposition, if $r$ is not true then we can't have both $p$ and $q$ be true .. which means that if one of them is true, then the other one is not.  So, the first statement does imply the second.

In fact, as it turns out, the second also implies the first. That one is not as intuitive, but here you need to equate the negation of a conditional with the truth of its antecedent and falsity of its consequent, i.e. $\neg(p \rightarrow q) \Leftrightarrow p \land \neg q$. That is: take the contrapositive of the second, and use this principle to get the first.

So the first two statements are equivalent.

For the third one: so here you again have $\neg r$, so once again you can't have both $p$ and $q$, and since you do have $q$, that means you can't have $p$. So the first implies the third.

And again, the third also implies the first, but that is a good bit harder to intuit.

Here is a useful principle that will help with these:

$p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow r) \Leftrightarrow (p \land q) \rightarrow r$ (this is called Exportation)

So:

$\neg r \rightarrow (p \rightarrow \neg q)$ (second statement) $\Leftrightarrow$ (Exportation)

$(\neg r \land p) \rightarrow \neg q)$  $\Leftrightarrow$ (Commutation)

$(p \land \neg r) \rightarrow \neg q)$  $\Leftrightarrow$ (Exportation)

$p \rightarrow (\neg r \rightarrow \neg q)$  $\Leftrightarrow$ (Contraposition)

$p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow r)$  $\Leftrightarrow$ (Exportation)

$(p \land q) \rightarrow r)$ (first statement) $\Leftrightarrow$ (Commutation)

$(q \land p) \rightarrow r)$ $\Leftrightarrow$ (Exportation)

$q \rightarrow (p \rightarrow r)$  $\Leftrightarrow$ (Contraposition)

$q \rightarrow (\neg r \rightarrow \neg p)$  $\Leftrightarrow$ (Exportation)

$(q \land \neg r) \rightarrow \neg p)$ (third statement)

So yes, all three are equivalent ... though I didn't use DeMorgan ...

Comment: hah beautiful, these sarcastic comm-enters telling me i'm wrong without helping.

Comment: Well, that was just about your very first sentence in your post, where you basically try to infer $(\neg p \lor \neg q) \rightarrow \neg r$ from $(p \land q) \rightarrow r$, which does not follow, so @fleablood was right about that. Moreover, fleablood even mentioned that that was the only sentence fleablood was commenting on.

Comment: i said if p or q doesnt happen then r doesnt happen.

Comment: if q and not p then not r, and if not q and p then not r

Comment: @Bobbyray  No, those are all mistaken inferences. Remember, when you take the contrapositive, you don't just negate the two sides, but you also have to swap them. That is, from $p \rightarrow q$ you can infer $\neg q \rightarrow \neg p$, but you **cannot** infer $\neg p \rightarrow \neg q$. But that is what you are effectively doing.